# Organize common item with uncommon item in a file using perl

Tags: perl

I have a file contains the data like this  3 columns. This may have thousands of lines. columns.

```
A    6:23   started 
A    7:12   completed
B    9:14   started
B   10:21   completed
C   12:33   started
C   13:44   completed
```

I want to get output like using perl

```
First_col   start_time  end_time  ( 3 columns)
A           6:23        7:12
B           9:14        10:21
C           12:33       13:44
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use 5.014;

my $idxLine = 0;
my @coll;
my $entry;
while (<>) {
    next if m/^$/; # Skip empty lines.
    if (++$idxLine % 2) {
        $entry = CEntry->new($_);
    }
    else {
        $entry->setCompleted($_);
        push(@coll, $entry);
    }
}

printf("%s %s %s\n", $_->{name}, $_->{start}, $_->{completed}) foreach @coll;

package CEntry;
use strict;
use 5.014;
sub new {
    my ($class, $name, $start) = ($_[0], (split(/\s/, $_[1]))[0,1]);
    return bless({name => $name, start => $start}, $class);
}
sub setCompleted {
    my ($self, $completed) = ($_[0], (split(/\s/, $_[1]))[1]);
    $self->{completed} = $completed;
}
```

Run:

```
$ cat data
A 6:23 started

A 7:12 completed

B 9:14 started

B 10:21 completed

C 12:33 started

C 13:44 completed
$ ./a.pl data
A 6:23 7:12
B 9:14 10:21
C 12:33 13:44
$ ./a.pl < data
A 6:23 7:12
B 9:14 10:21
C 12:33 13:44
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a substitution like this:

```
s/([A-Z])( [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}) started \1((?2)) completed/$1$2$3/g
```

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/iE3xA7/1)

or shorter, you can remove what you don't want:

```
s/ started [A-Z]| completed//g
```